# Extends generic type with optional properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extend a generic type to let the function know that the generic type **could** have those properties, but then when I pass an object it requires those properties to be on the object.

```js
type TWithParams = {
    ignore?: boolean
}
function printList<T extends TWithParams>(items: T[], itemAccessor: (i: T) => string) {
    items.forEach(i => {
        if (!i.ignore) {
            console.log(itemAccessor(i))
        }
    })
}
```

I should have to extends all the object that I pass to the function with the optional params, and it's kinda annoying.

```js
type Fruit = {
    name: string
}
const fruits: Fruit[] = [
    {name: 'Banana'},
    {name: 'Strawberry'},
    {name: 'Apple'},
]

printList(fruits, i => i.name) // this does not work

const fruitsWithIgnore: (Fruit & TWithParams)[] = [
    {name: 'Banana'},
    {name: 'Strawberry'},
    {name: 'Apple'},
]

printList(fruitsWithIgnore, i => i.name) // this works
```

Is it possible to make the first function works without extending the type?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg6gS2ACwAoEMBO6C2BnKAXigG8AoKSqBAcwDsB7TCAfgC4oAjBhgGwnR0yAXzIAzAK50AxsAQM6UMJgR1gAGQR5gAHhhQIAD2AQ6AEwLwkaLLjwA+ABRII+DjADaAXQA01EzgAgtLSEHh4TBzO7gCURPZQ2ip0NHHkVP6ueAB0YkwAoujSyM7xpBQZVAhiUI4AhAjZtIzMaRWVldIKEfzZvAw0zgHBoeFMzjEx7ZWiGcJTomSgkFAAYpgSSETlGXS4EBxJqjQiZF102lBiG0h4HOubwN7bHtMkezgHUADkAEKCAO+wh8bw+X2+AGVgNgAO6cCCYTAgIEgjLvfYcb6BMBgfgosheMhkZSqDRaYCOa6PPB+BBlRpgqZnbrAK43YB4RAoACS9CYX0cDy2ADJYFybNh8DFnsRXmiwZj-ns9vj5RiflDYfDEcjgaD1VicXi9YTickydpKezOdZeS0ILT6dlGUA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the `printList` like this:

```js
function printList<T>(items: (T & TWithParams)[], itemAccessor: (i: T & TWithParams) => string) {
    items.forEach(i => {
        if (!i.ignore) {
            console.log(itemAccessor(i))
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is way simpler than I thought. I wonder why I did stick with extends instead of trying with the union.

Well it doesn't matter, thank you for your help!